# I am trying to parse data on two delimiters

Tags: shell-script, csv

So what I'm trying to do is for this:
    looking at the example CSV:

```
1,3917,3917,BGP=694|Ethernet=1610|LAG=3,Y
```

After the script is run, the output should look similar to:

```
1,3917,3917,BGP=694,Y
1,3917,3917,Ethernet=1610,Y
1,3917,3917,LAG=3,Y
```

One line of original CSV file that contained additional delimiters is now converted into 3 lines because there were three additional fields within the 4th column.

I've been working on it all day and this is what I've come up with.
Will it work?

Code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh
   if [ $# -ne 1 ];
     then echo "Usage: read.sh filename";
     exit 1;
    fi
   file="$1"
   while read line
     do
       IFS='|'
       set x $line
       while [ a -le #$]
         do
           a=a+1
           echo "`$1`,`$a`"
         done
     done < $1
```

Comment: why is this tagged as `/tcsh` when the script is `ksh`?  also you need to be a lot clearer about what it is that you're trying to do.  start from the beginning, describe your actual goal, not the (possibly wrong or less-than-optimal) method you've chosen to implement....there may be a much better/easier way to do it, probably involving `awk`

Comment: Actually, the tcsh was a fat finger I did not see.

Comment: As for using awk, the request came as just shell and not using awk

Comment: As for what I'm trying to do                                   As the  top of the post says,         1,3917,3917,BGP=694|Ethernet=1610|LAG=3,Y

After the script is run, the output should look similar to:

1,3917,3917,BGP=694,Y
1,3917,3917,Ethernet=1610,Y
1,3917,3917,LAG=3,Y

One line of original CSV file that contained additional delimiters is now converted into 3 lines because there were three additional fields within the 4th column.

Comment: yes, i read that the first time.  i wouldn't have asked for clarification if it meant anything to me.  and, as i asked, please state your goal not your method.

Comment: as for using awk - use the right tool for the job...and awk is a standard shell tool, perfectly appropriate for use in a shell script.  BTW, is this a homework question?  nothing wrong with posting them here, but it's polite to identify them as such.

Comment: No, this is not a homework question.  It was a question asked of me as I know a little Unix.  The person who asked me had heard of awk but does not know it so he wanted something he did have an easy chance to understand.   I hoped that posting the "start" and expected result, that I would be understood enough to be advised where I went wrong.  Sorry to have bothered you

Comment: @Marc No offence, but if people ask me to do something in a cumbersome and complicated way, I will suggest an easy to understand and less comprehensive approach (such as using `awk`) if I know one. If you don't understand `awk`, you should learn it!

Comment: The job comes before the choice of tool always - one hammer does not fit all tasks.  `awk` was designed for processing text that comes in columns, and I'd agree that it is better than shell for this task.

Comment: Your single example leaves a few open questions: assuming the input is CSV, is it always the 4th field that has pipes?  Are any of the fields allowed to contain commas? (Some CSV formats allow including commas via certain escape mechanisms like double-quotes)

Answer (score 3):

### Use AWK Instead

This problem is much easier to solve with AWK. I tested this with GNU AWK; if you're using something else, you may need to tweak it a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { FS = "|" }

{
  split( $3, array, /,/ )
  print $1 "," array[2]
  print $1 "," $2 "," array[2]
  print $1 "," $3
}
```

Store the script somewhere (e.g. *parse.awk*) and make sure it's executable. You can then call the script on a CSV file or on standard input, and collect your results like this:

```
$ echo '1,3917,3917,BGP=694|Ethernet=1610|LAG=3,Y' | parse.awk
1,3917,3917,BGP=694,Y
1,3917,3917,BGP=694,Ethernet=1610,Y
1,3917,3917,BGP=694,LAG=3,Y
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  Will it be able to handle a line that is similar but has different numbers of comma and/or pipe delimited fields in it?

Comment: @Marc Maybe. You'll have to try it to find out whether it works with *your* irregular data. If you have irregular data then you may need to fix the data file, discard irregular records, or write a much more complex parser. Poorly-delimited data is always a problem for any programmatic solution.

Comment: with a sample of only one line it's impossible to tell if it will work on all possible input lines.  if there are variations then you need to show them.

Comment: @CodeGnome   thanks for your efforts.  I'll take this to my friend.

Comment: @Craig.  Sorry for the one liner.  the space available restricted me.  I had to cut over 500 characters from my original post.   Again, I'm sorry I bothered you

Comment: i'm not bothered - i'm just pointing out that if you want help, then you need to provide the information required to do that.  we can't read your mind and we can't see the actual input file.

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to be a field with grouped values separated by a pipe symbol.

You may use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to "explode" these grouped values into separate new records:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N nest --evar pipe -f 4 file
1,3917,3917,BGP=694,Y
1,3917,3917,Ethernet=1610,Y
1,3917,3917,LAG=3,Y
```

This reads the input from `file` as a header-less CSV file and then applies the `nest` operation, exploding the pipe-delimited sub-fields in the 4th field into new records.

You may also do the opposite, i.e. "implode" the 4th field's values into a combined field delimited by pipes.

```bash
$ cat file
1,3917,3917,BGP=694,Y
1,3917,3917,Ethernet=1610,Y
1,3917,3917,LAG=3,Y
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N nest --ivar pipe -f 4 file
1,3917,3917,BGP=694|Ethernet=1610|LAG=3,Y
```

Since Miller is CSV-aware, there will be no issues with data containing fields with embedded commas or newlines.